# How to create Gaussian Noise texture in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, gaussian

I need to create a texture like the below one with the specific key is there any way of creating this using python?
Also, I need to extract the texture from another image and compare using this.Basically, the idea is, I will create a texture using Gaussian Noise and I will distribute it.After that when someone sends the texture back to me I want to know whether the texture is same as that i send

Texture image

[image]

Comment: Did you try to Google it before asking? There are plenty of articles about generating Gaussian noise with Python.

Comment: Couldn't find the correct implementation. i need a solution for texture comparison also. @AndriyMakukha

Comment: Firstly, it's unclear what you mean by texture comparison. Secondly, when asking questions on SO, you need to show effort: what have you tried? Where is your code? What libraries are you using?

Comment: @AndriyMakukha I used LBP texture matching, but the accuracy was bad. Texture comparison is nothing but comparing the features of two images, i.e, variance, entropy and etc. I think you are unfamiliar with image processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to answer the question asked in the title, here's how you generate and save Gaussian noise texture in Python using numpy and cv2:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

SHAPE = (150, 200)

noise = np.random.normal(255./2, 255./10, SHAPE)
cv2.imwrite("gaussian_noise.png", noise)
```

And using numpy and Pillow:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

SHAPE = (150, 200)

noise = np.random.normal(255./2, 255./10, SHAPE)
image = Image.fromarray(noise)
image = image.convert('RGB')
image.save("gaussian_noise.png")
```

Example output:

[image: Gaussian noise 200 by 150 pixels, mean = 127.5, dev = 25.5]

As to the second part of your question, it's really unclear and ambiguous. You should show your code in order for people on StackOverflow to help you.